# ASP.NET Nested GridView, DataItem returns null in child GridView's RowDataBound Event

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In a nested GridView (GridView inside a template column of parent GridView). I am binding child GridView to a DataTable in parent GridView's RowDataBound event. this works as it should. But the problem i am facing is in Child GridView's RowDataBound Event, when i try to access e.Row.DataItem property it returns null. I am expecting it to return DataRowView Type. which i will then use to set values of TextBox's.

Parent GridViewId = gvProductOptionGrps and
Child GridViewId = gvProductOptions

Parent GridViews RowDataBound Event.

```
    protected void gvProductOptionGrps_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //ProductOptionGrps
            TextBox txtProductOptionGrpSortOrder = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtProductOptionGrpSortOrder");
            Label lblProductOptionGrpName = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblProductOptionGrpName");
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

            txtProductOptionGrpSortOrder.Text = drv["SortOrder"].ToString();
            lblProductOptionGrpName.Text = drv["Name"].ToString();

            //ProductOptions
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT a.ProductOptionId,a.SortOrder,b.Name,b.PriceGBP" +
                                 " FROM ProductOptionGrpProductOptions a" +
                                 " INNER JOIN ProductOptions b ON a.ProductOptionId=b.ProductOptionId" +
                                 " WHERE a.ProductOptionGrpId=@ProductOptionGrpId" +
                                 " ORDER BY a.SortOrder";
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductOptionGrpId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new Guid(drv["ProductOptionGrpId"].ToString());
            _fl.ConnectToSQLServer();
            sqlCmd.Connection = _fl.GetActiveSQLServerConnection();

            DataTable dtProductOptions = new DataTable();
            dtProductOptions.Load(sqlCmd.ExecuteReader());

            GridView gv = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvProductOptions");
            gv.DataSource = dtProductOptions;
            gv.DataBind();
            _fl.DisconnectFromSQLServer();
        }
    }

    protected void gvProductOptions_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtProductOptionSortOrder = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtProductOptionSortOrder");
        TextBox txtPriceGBP = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtPriceGBP");
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;//returns null

        txtProductOptionSortOrder.Text = drv["SortOrder"].ToString();//Error
        txtPriceGBP.Text = drv["PriceGBP"].ToString();//Error
    }
```

Comment: You should have edited your original question instead of creating a new one. It would have been pushed up if you have edited it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626621/dataitem-is-null-in-nested-gridviews-rowdatabound-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to check if the Row is a DataRow in `gvProductOptions_RowDataBound`. The Header does not have a DataItem hence it is null.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
```