# About binding data to dynamically created dropdown in gridview in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one check box & 2 radiobuttons & 1 dropdownlist. 
I have created 5 controls(textbox,2 dropdownlist,textbox, textbox) dynamically in gridview in chkboxindex changed event according to the selected no in dropdownlist.
For that i have added ItemTemplate(to display data),EditItemTemplate(to edit data),FooterTemplate(to insert data) in gridview for each control. I have Added link to add data, after clicking Add link data gets added & appears in gridview and Add link replace with edit link.
I have to bind data to both dropdownlists in gridview according to the condition(depend on the radiobuttons selected if its value 0 then some record to be bind & if it is one then all data to be bind). I have given query for that, but its applicable for only one record not for  the others.
What should i do for that?
How i can solve this problem? Please help me?
Asp.net c#
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For custom binding/ hierarchical biding check RowDataBound GridView event.

[How to find controls and bind custom data row by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633261/asp-net-nested-gridview-dataitem-returns-null-in-child-gridviews-rowdatabound-e)

[Another reference](http://forums.asp.net/t/1223702.aspx/1)