# Why is the DataItem null for a GridView row "null" when trying to save changes?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

So I've got this GridView on my web page. It is databound, so during the RowDataBound event this code works perfectly well:

```
    protected void myGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TimecardApproval shift = (TimecardApproval)e.Row.DataItem;
        }
    }
```

The "shift" variable has all the data I need, works great. But then there's this code for saving the data:

```
    protected void btnSubmitApprovals_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow item in gvTimeCards.Rows)
        {
            TimecardApproval shift = (TimecardApproval)item.DataItem;
            // code to update the row
        }
    }
```

The DataItem is null! Why? Since the field is there, it seems strange that it's null. Should I be looping over something else?

Comment: `DataItem` is set during  databinding. On postbacks it's always null until you `DataBind` the GridView again. Note that all variables are disposed at the end of the page-lifecycle.  What exactly do you need in `btnSubmitApprovals_Click`? Normally you get it from the controls in the Bound-/TemplateFields.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The documentation says: _The DataItem property is only available during and after the RowDataBound event of a GridView control_. Can you clarify the "after" portion?

Comment: @codingbiz: _After_ means after it was databound in the same page life-cycle (so until `Unload`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, getting the original DataItem seemed the most logical way to find out which fields had been modified. So are you saying I can rebind the GridView in the click function?

Comment: @TheGerm: No you cannot rebind the GridView. Then you would override all changes and prevent events from being raised. You need to evaluate the controls or use the GridView [`RowUpdating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx) event with its `OldValues` and `NewValues` properties.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I understand you may want to have intellisense by casting DataItem to TimeCardApproval. You can do this instead. Use the DataKeyNames to store the Primary Key of each row which should be `TimecardApprovalID` and in your code access the primary key and use it to get the original item

```
foreach (GridViewRow item in gvTimeCards.Rows)
{
   //get the ID of the TimeApproval for each row
   string id = gvDocs.DataKeys[item.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
   //string id = ((HiddenField) item.FindControl("IDHiddenField")).Value;
   //string id = item.Cells[0].Text;

   //use the ID or get TimeCardApproval object from DB    
   TimecardApproval shift = MyDB.GetTimeCardApproval(id);

}
```

Setting the Keys

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTimeCards" DataKeyNames="TimecardApprovalID">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: This worked like a champ for me, though I think the better method is to use the RowUpdating action. Also, I had no problem casting the DataItem, but I couldn't figure out how to get the DataItem or how to get a reference to look it up. This DataKey information was very useful. Thanks! Could you edit your answer to say, "This is how to get a reference to the original item", so I can accept this answer?

Comment: Just a follow-up. I actually have to go this route, because the dataSource that the GridView is using does not have an "update" function. Quite the crash-course into ASP.NET.

Comment: Found this a lot more helping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633261/asp-net-nested-gridview-dataitem-returns-null-in-child-gridviews-rowdatabound

Comment: What's about ***performance***? access to DB (using the ID) for each row ? 30 rows, 30 calls to DB ?

Comment: @Kiquenet You could cache your data or use in-memory collection

Comment: What is `gvDocs`?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, this help you
Grid column:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item ID">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>'/>
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfDataItem" Value='<%# JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Container.DataItem) %>'/>
</ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void btApply_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rows = (from GridViewRow row in gvResult.Rows
            where row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow
            let dataItem = (HiddenField) row.FindControl("hfDataItem")
            select JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultGridRowItem>(dataItem.Value));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The gridview databind event fires before the button click. Sounds wierd but that's [asp.net page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) craziness.
Try using your code in gridview `RowUpdating` or `RowUpdated` event.

Comment: I don't know whether I want to update the row until I know what the original value is. But perhaps you're saying that each row should take care of its own updating? That I can "cancel out" of a row update if I want to?

Comment: Yes, `e.Cancel` is what you're talking about.